# Pin bottom of div to bottom of screen

Tags: html, css

Given...

```
<html>
   <body>
      <div id="row1">...</div>
      <div id="row2" style="overflow-y: scroll;">...</div>
   </body>
</html>
```

Given `row2`'s content being taller than the remaining vertical space, how do I pin the bottom of `row2` to the bottom of the viewport such that the div scrolls to show the contained content?

`row1`'s height varies based on its content.

Comment: What have you already tried?

Comment: A bit confusing as to exactly what you need but it seems it could be address by using flexbox. Here's a [helpful resource](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/).

Comment: flexbox doesn't work because it doesn't seem to limit divs vertically. Generally, it seems that HTML stretches divs vertically as tall as they need to be unless they're given an explicit height or the edges are pinned using absolute positioning.

Comment: Can a javascript solution also work for the same?

Comment: Yes, that what I'm going to use.

Answer (score 0):

```css
body{
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
    margin: 0 auto;
}

row1{
    position:relative;
    max-height:50%;
    height:100%;
}

row2{
    position:fixed;
    max-height:50%;
    height:100%;
    overflow-y:scroll;
}
```

```html
<html>
   <body>
      <div id="row1">...</div>
      <div id="row2" style="overflow-y: scroll;">...</div>
   </body>
</html>
```

Comment: 50% isn't how much space is left though.

Comment: Are you providing an answer or asking a question? This should have been a comment on the question.

Comment: Glad it's not me in trouble this time.